# Как преобразовать JPG в массив NumPy?

Tags: python, изображения, numpy, обработка-изображений, jpeg

Как преобразовать JPG изображение в трехмерный массив NumPy, в котором каждый пиксель будет представлен вектором из трёх чисел?

Первое из которых, обозначает красный цвет, второе - зелёный, а третье - синий, т.е. RGB.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image    #  pip install Pillow

img = np.asarray(Image.open('image.jpg').convert('RGB'))
```